# How to set cursor in Storyboard

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to change cursor when my video player's media transport controls fade out. I want to hide it when controls fade out.
I want to add it here:

```
    `<VisualState x:Name="ControlPanelFadeOut">
     <Storyboard>
     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CoreCursorType">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Hand" />
     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
     </VisualState>`
```

Comment: I think you can set Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor

Comment: @lindexi I've heard that doesn't work in uwp. Sadly OP hardly gave us anything to work with. are you using c#? Vb? Try to give us more info and what exactly you need

Comment: You should write some code in .cs, can I use the code?

Comment: If you want request microsoft to integrate the above future, you can vote up the following request [UWP XAML MediaElement auto hide cursor on fullscreen mode](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/11295156-uwp-xaml-mediaelement-auto-hide-cursor-on-fullscre).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should write a property in code.

```
      public static readonly DependencyProperty CursorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Cursor", typeof(string), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor((CoreCursorType) Enum.Parse(typeof(CoreCursorType), (string) e.NewValue), 0);
            }
            else
            {
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);

            }
        }));

    public string Cursor
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(CursorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CursorProperty, value); }
    }
```

When you set the Cursor that will set the cursor.

And you can change the Cursor in xaml and please see the code.

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Page" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Cursor">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="IBeam"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState.Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I write that when the windows size is bigger than 720 that will use IBeam and I think you can use it.

You can download all the code in [github](https://github.com/lindexi/lindexi_gd/tree/c365e7514fd0ea8c6f9d6277789829737d5b6921/UhajoloraKdzvhy)